# How can i update Pivot tables in excel dynamically?

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, range, pivot-table

```
Option Explicit
Sub DPTR()

 With Application
     .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
     .EnableEvents = False
     .ScreenUpdating = False
 End With



 Dim startcell As Range, lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long
 Dim ws, wsPivot As Worksheet
 Dim pvtName As String, rngPivot As Range, strNewData As String

 Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(4)
 Set wsPivot = Sheet8
 pvtName = "CFN"

 Set startcell = ws.Range("A1")

 lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, startcell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
 lastCol = ws.Cells(startcell.Row + 1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

 Set rngPivot = ws.Range(startcell, ws.Cells(lastRow, lastCol))

 strNewData = ws.Name & "!" & rngPivot.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

'If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(rngPivot.Rows(1)) > 0 Then
'MsgBox "One of the source data columns contains a blank heading." & vbNewLine _ & "Please add a 
 heading and run the macro again", vbCritical, _
 '"Source data Column heading missing"

 'On Error GoTo Reset
'End If

wsPivot.PivotTables(pvtName).ChangePivotCache ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, 
SourceData:=strNewData)

wsPivot.PivotTables(pvtName).RefreshTable

Reset:
    With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
   End With
End Sub
```

The code above throws a runtime error 5. I tried to do everything I could to fix it, but I am unable to. Can anyone please help me with it?

I am trying to update the range of a pivot table dynamically.

Comment: Please clarify which line of code throws the error.

Comment: Hit F9 over, and over, and over, until you get the exact error message.  Post back with the specific error message.